# Regex to match url patterns

Tags: java, regex

I know this is a very simple question but since I am very bad in regex , have to ask below question. 
I want to write a regex expression in java which will match below two url patterns given  :

```
{contextPath}/javax.faces.resource/**

{contextPath}/rfRes/**
```

The url will be read from http request object and will be compared using java pattern object like below  :

```
Pattern p = //regex here ;
p.matcher(r.getRequestURL().toString()).matches();
```

Can anybody help me in writing a regex experion for above two urls ?

Comment: Are you matching literal `**` in URL?

Comment: It indicates anything after / .So its a wildcard entry there

Comment: Do you have a `HttpServletRequest` reference to be able to get context path?

Comment: No , we don't have . But do we really need it ? We are not matching for contextPath. It can be anything .What we need to match is path in between.

Comment: Do you really regex for this? Just use `request.getRequestURI()` and get first part

Comment: Yes , but I cannot change existing mechanism . Have to use regex for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
boolean matches = r.getRequestURI().matches(".*?/(javax\.faces\.resource|rfRes)/.*");
```

Comment: Thanks for your repply. But I suppose , above expression will match exactly for /javax.faces.resource/[any character] . But what is needed is [any character]/javax.faces.resource/[any character]. Does /*(javax.faces.resource|rfRes).* will work ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
.*?(?:\/javax\.faces\.resource\/|\/rfRes\/).*$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/rV5mR8/2

It checks whether the string start with either of the two options which you want.

Comment: Thanks aelor for repply . We really don't need contextPath. It can be anything . We just need to check javax.faces.resource/** and /rfRes/**. In that case , do we need contextPath in regex expression ?